# Vectorizing function on arrays in DataFrame column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, apply

I want to use a function (scipy.signal.savgol_filter) on every element in a Dataframe column (every element of the column is an array). While looping seems a little unnecessary, I can't wrap my head around a vectorized solution.

I tried the obvious .apply method as well as just using the function on the column. Both show an error like "setting an array element with a sequence".

Example code with lists instead of arrays (but same results):

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal 
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [[1,3,9], [7,2,3], [3,2,6,3], [2,3,4]]})
df['smooth'] = df.apply(signal.savgol_filter, args=(3, 0))
```

Respectively:

```py
df['smooth'] = signal.savgol_filter(df['A'], 3, 0)
```

Or:

```py
df['smooth'] = signal.savgol_filter(df['A'].values, 3, 0)
```

None of those work, I think because the whole column is given to the function.
Is there a way to use the function on all the elements (=arrays) in the column at the same time or do i have to loop over every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your elements aren't the same shape when trying to treat it as a multidimensional array.

If you just want to apply that function to each row you need to select the column explicitly:

```
df['smooth'] = df['A'].apply(signal.savgol_filter, args=(3, 0))
```

This is not really a vectorized solution, though.

Edit:

It's worth adding that there is discussion over on the `numpy` issue tracker about the ambiguity of this error message.

See [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5303) and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6584)